# Proving integration by parts formula using divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, vector-analysis

I'm working on an exercise that requires me to prove the integration by parts formula

$$\int_{\Omega}u_{x_j}v\ dx=-\int_{\Omega}uv_{x_j}\ dx+\int_{\partial\Omega}\nu_j uv\ dS$$

by use of the divergence theorem

$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla  F\ dx=\int_{\partial\Omega}\nu\cdot F dS$$

where $\nu$ denotes the outward pointing normal to $\partial\Omega$.

I don't exactly know how I would go about doing this, so any help/hints are highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply the divergence theorem to $$F=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\uv\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$
where the $uv$ is in the $j$-th entry.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I solved it now!

Answer (score 0):

Let $F=(0,0,\ldots,0,uv,0,\ldots,0)$, where uv is the jth coordinate.

Then

$\nabla \cdot F=(uv)_{x_j}=u_{x_j}v + uv_{x_j} \ and \ F \cdot \nu =uv\nu^{j}$.

Now,

$\int_{\Omega}(u_{x_j}v+uv_{x_j})dx=\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot F dx=\int_{\partial \Omega} F \cdot \nu dS = \int_{\partial \Omega} uv\nu^{j} dS$

Comment: Isn't this the same as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, just added the derivation in more detail.